# "I raised my score" or "I increased my score"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Are both these sentences correct, and is one of them better than the other for everyday language ?

> I raised my score.

Or

> I increased my score.

Comment: both are correct, I would prefer `increase` probably because raise has variety of meanings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both valid.

I would prefer "increased" for everyday usage, as it feels more quantitative. To me, "raised" can imply a more physical raising, or, a non-incremental raising, e.g., "raising the bar", which is often used to mean setting a higher standard, but is based on the idea of physically raising a bar. "Raise" is generally less quantitative and more qualitative.

Comment: ***Raise*** isn't always "more physical raising". Idiomatically, it's always ***raise my game***, where it's effectively synonymous with ***improve** [my performance at the game]* - and nobody ever refers to a need to ***increase** their game*.

Comment: I see what you mean; I was attempting to describe it as being qualitative as opposed to quantitative, and thought physicality seemed liked a good analogy, or that it has a similar feel. I've changed my answer a bit so I'm not claiming that physical aspect so exclusively.